# Accessing an array in JSON object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON object in javascript returned by a PHP web service :

```
data={
"result": "pass",
"error_type": "",
"feedback_ids": {
    "feedback0": "1",
    "feedback1": "8"
},
"redirect_uri": ""
}
```

alert(data.result) works like a peach. How do I access "feedback_ids" and alert feedback0 and feedback1?

Comment: may be u havent parsed the JSON. Parse the JSON and then try it . 
var parsedObj = JSON.parse(data) ;
alert(parsedObj.result);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access those variables you need to do:

```
data.feedback_ids.feedback0
```

and

```
data.feedback_ids.feedback1
```

If you have flexibility on server, make your life easier by changing that to JSON Array so you could loop them by their index. Note below I just changed the feedback_ids to the array structure

```
data={
"result": "pass",
"error_type": "",
"feedback_ids": [
    "1",
    "8"
],
"redirect_uri": ""
}
```

Comment: Hey Momo. I started with that! But everytime I alert it I am getting "undefined" as the result!!

Comment: Did you try data.feedback_ids[0]?

Comment: I tried with the code I had as well as format you provided. Its still undefined.

Comment: This is the callback function from PHP : catch_merchant_feedback({"result":"pass","error_type":"","feedback_ids":["1","8"],"redirect_uri":""})

Comment: Hmmm, I just tried that in Firebug Console and it worked. Have you tried loading the page with Firebug and just output it in the console to see what kind of JSON structure you are getting? If possible, maybe post the client' side code as well

Comment: Alright my bad!! :D ... I forgot to export the tables on production!! Dammnnn meeee...

Comment: @sniper let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3017/discussion-between-momo-and-sniper)

Answer (score 1):

To get at the `feedback_ids`:

```
ids = data.feedback_ids;
```

And to get inside that:

```
one   = data.feedback_ids.feedback0;
eight = data.feedback_ids.feedback1;
```

You could also use array notation:

```
one = data['feedback_ids']['feedback0'];
```

Comment: I am getting "undefined" when I try to alert the data. What am I doing wrong? I am very sure that the data is present!

Answer (score 0):

`data.feedback_ids.feedback0` and `data.feedback_ids.feedback1`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var k in data.feedback_ids) {
    console.log(k, data.feedback_ids[k]); 
}
```

This code will output:

```
feedback0, 1
feedback1, 8
```